# Multi Level Dependent Variable Statistical Test

Tags: r, statistical-significance, inference, sas

I have a multi level dependent variable. The dependent variable is Tenure -  less than 1 year, 1-2 year and above 2 years.

The independent variable is AHT. I need to conduct a statistical test whether the tenure is significant in relation to the AHT.

What is the statistical test that i can conduct. Have tried researching but cant figure out.

Comment: What is AHT?  Is it continuous or discrete?

Comment: AHT is average handle time and it is continuous.